# how to implement math formula

Tags: iphone, ipad, math, xcode4.2

I have to implement the math equation in my iPhone application. but I don't know how to implement. Is it required to add framework for calculation purpose?

```
My formula :0.00005*t^3 + 0.0045*t^2 + 0.7542*t + 23.459 = p
```

One more question for maths: I have `p` value and from find the `t` can any one help me to solve this equation or help me to how to find t.

Comment: You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.00005*t%5E3+%2B+0.0045*t%5E2+%2B+0.7542*t+%2B+23.459+%3D+p) to solve for t in terms of p

Answer (score 1):

You want the formulas for the roots of a cubic equation - you can get them from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)

Comment: More generally, what the OP is looking for is a way to find the roots of an equation. This might slightly off topic here.

Comment: The formula provided in the OP is a cubic one, and the linked page contains several methods of finding said roots - Therefore I believe it is right on the topic?

Comment: Indeed it is. I was just pointing out that his *specific* question could be made more useful by pointing towards a more generally applicable concept. However, it is appropriate to point him towards roots of the cubic equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply evaluate the equation, you can just implement as the following function:

```
double f(double t)
{
    return 0.00005 * (t * t * t) + 0.0045 * (t * t) + 0.7542 * t + 23.459;
}
```

If you want to find the root of the equation, you have two options: Analytic solutions and numerically. Analytically, you can only find the roots for a small set of polynomials ([Linear,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) [Quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula), [Cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots), and [Quartic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation)) In general, most polynomials are difficult if not impossible to find an analytic solution for.

The link I provided for the Cubic equation shows you how to solve for the roots of your equation. I will not repeat them here, as it's rather easy to implement. If you want a "simpler" way to find the root of an equation, you can use what's known as Newton's Method.

You can write your function as `f(t, p) = 0.00005 * t^3 + 0.0045 * t^2 + 0.7542 * t + 23.459 - p`. Since you know the equation, you can calculate it's derivative and use [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to solve for *one* of the roots:

```
double FindRoot(double t0, double p)
{
    double eps = 1E-6; // The accuracy of the found root
    double t;
    do
    {
        t = t0;
        double f  = 0.00005 * t * t * t + 0.0045 * t * t + 0.7542 * t + 23.459 - p;
        double fp = 0.00015 * t * t + 0.009 * t + 0.7542;
        t0 = t - f / fp;
    } while(abs(t - t0) > eps);

    return t0;
}
```

You must provide a starting location for where to look for the first root. You should be careful in choosing this, as the starting location determines which root it converges to and whether it converges at all.

Answer (score -1):

No need to implement extra frameworks.

You can do as follows:

```
double p = 0.00005*pow(t, 3) + 0.0045*pow(t, 2) + 0.7542*t + 23.459;
```

And to find the `t`, you have to solve the cubic equation as given in [this](http://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/YBA/cyg-X1-mass/cubic.html) link

Comment: If you read the question he has the p value and wants to solve for t